# Silex autoload permission denied

Tags: autoload, silex

I have following problem. In index.html i have

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And I got this error.

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9
```

But for whole /var/www/html i set permission by "chmod -R 777"

Where can I make a mistake?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these two commands :

```
chown www-data: ./* -R
```

And :

```
chmod 775 ./* -R
```

(Supposing you are in the `/var/www/html` folder)